# fsockopen fgets for only a few seconds and close. Dont wait for full byte count. Just read for a few seconds

Tags: php, tcp, fsockopen

I have the following code

It essentially connects to a local server , sends a command and reads the data back (128bytes.)
However, Sometimes its 1000 bytes, others its 4 bytes.

How can I get it so it just reads for a few seconds and closes then outputs the data it received?

I cant find anything on google to do this.
The server just sends the data and then essentially goes silent (no disconnect etc) so i just want to read for a few seconds into a variable and thats it.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("localhost", 3332, $errno, $errstr, 3);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "FSBC004000");

        echo fgets($fp, 128);

    fclose($fp);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

ALways the case! Spend days looking for the answer.. Post to Stackoverflow... answer it myself within minutes,. ffs

Need to use:
stream_set_timeout($fp, 2);